# How to invoke an Objective-C Block via the LLVM C++ API?

Tags: llvm, objective-c-blocks

Say, for example, I have an Objective-C compiled Module that contains something like the following:

```
typedef bool (^BoolBlock)(void);
BoolBlock returnABlock(void)
{
    return Block_copy(^bool(void){
        printf("Block executing.\n");
        return YES;
    });
}
```

...then, using the LLVM C++ API, I load that Module and create a CallInst to call the `returnABlock()` function:

```
Function *returnABlockFunction = returnABlockModule->getFunction(std::string("returnABlock"));
CallInst *returnABlockCall = CallInst::Create(returnABlockFunction, "returnABlockCall", entryBlock);
```

How can I then invoke the Block returned via the `returnABlockCall` object?

Answer (score 2):

Not an easy answer here, I'm afraid. Blocks are lowered by the front-end into calls into the blocks runtime. In the case of clang, the relevant code is at `clang/lib/CodeGen/CGBlocks.[h|cpp]`.

It would be worth asking on the [cfe-dev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/) list if there's a way to factor this code out for reuse in other front-ends.

Comment: Thanks, ohmantics.  I'll dig through that part of the clang source sometime.

Answer (score 0):

In C, I just act as if the var I assigned the block to was a function pointer.  Using your code as an example, after you assign the result of the function to "returnABlockCall", you could just write:

```
returnABlockCall();
```

and it should work.

Warning, this is untested in C++, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Although I see now you wanted to invoke it using the LLVM API, and I just invoked it directly, so it's very likely I'm just wrong, and wrong in a public forum to boot.

Comment: Yeah, if I were to do `returnABlockCall()`, that would dereference/jump to the `CallInst` class pointer, not the pointer to the block my function returns.  The actual block pointer won't exist at that point --- I'm just using the LLVM API to construct the call graph; it doesn't get executed until later on.